# System limit for number of file watchers reached on Heroku

Tags: linux, heroku

I deployed a node application with following libreoffice buildpack: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/bluetealondon/heroku-buildpack-libreoffice-for-heroku-18

But while my application tries to start on Heroku, it spits out following error:

```
Internal watch failed: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/app/vendor/libreoffice/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/mimetypes/libreoffice6.4-presentation-template.svg'
```

Obviously I found that I need to increase the limit, but on Heroku I don't have sudo access.
My question is now, how can I fix this? Because I need the Libreoffice buildpack for my application.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?